# Returning a value based on index number of each element in a list

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops, return-value

I am trying to identify the first element, last element, and other elements in a python list using a function.
If it’s the first element, I want 0 to be returned, if it’s the last element I want -1 to be returned, every other element should return 2.

I can achieve this without using a function but when I use a function, I don’t get the desired result.
Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

What I have so far can be seen in the codes and screenshots below
[here is the code without using a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJTui.jpg)

```
a= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        if i==0:
            number=0 
        elif i==len(a)-1:
            number=-1
        else:
            number=2 
        print (number)
```

[here is the desired output, it is gotten when function is not used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGiXJ.jpg)

[here is the same code in a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h58xT.jpg)

```
def cs():
    a= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        if i==0:
            number=0 
        elif i==len(a)-1:
            number=-1
        else:
            number=2 
        print (number)
        return (number)
cs()
```

[here is the output of the function. it returns only one index instead of six](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13Rnx.jpg)

If i try having the print/return statement outside the for loop, only the last element returns a value.

```
def cs():
    a= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        if i==0:
            number=0 
        elif i==len(a)-1:
            number=-1
        else:
            number=2 
    print (number)
    return (number)
cs()
```

[here is the output of the function with the print/return statement outside the for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvKEC.jpg)

Comment: Never post code as images, simply copy/paste the code directly to your question and format it as code.

Comment: you have a `return` statement in your function. this exits the function, after the first iteration of the loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Comment: @JeanotZubler thanks for your response! is it possible to iterate through the whole list and still use a return statement?

Comment: @Cassie we use `yield` this will not exit the function.

Comment: @RandomGuy not really. I need the code to return a particular value for the first element, another value the last element, and then the same value for the “middle” elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query- **is it possible to iterate through the whole list and still use a return statement?**

Instead of `return` we use `yield` to go through whole list.

```
def generator():
    a= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    for i,x in enumerate(a):
        if i==0:
            yield 0 
        elif i==len(a)-1:
            yield -1
        else:
            yield 2

gen_object = generator()
print(type(gen_object))
for i in gen_object:
   print(i)
```

**Output:-**

```
<class 'generator'>
0
2
2
2
2
-1
```